# Run javascript does not run CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need some help in Javascript and CSS. I have a script that is working fine but when i perform the filtering function on top, my CSS will not run and only the filtered result will be show in the HTML page. Seek for advise in performing the javascript.

```
<script>
      var createTable = function(){
      var street = document.getElementById("search-street").value;
      var suburb = document.getElementById("search-suburb").value;
      var pc = document.getElementById("search-pc").value;
      var type = document.getElementById("search-type").value;
      var counter=0;
      if (street == '' && suburb == '' && pc == '' && type == '') {
        for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
          var id = myArray[i][4];
          if(counter%3==0){
            document.write("<div class='row'>");
          }
          document.write("<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>");
          document.write("<div class='thumbnail'>");
          document.write("<div class='caption'>");
          document.write("<p>" + myArray[i][3] + "</p>");
          document.write("<p><a href='edit_property.php?id="+id+"' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Edit</a> <a href='#delete_property.php?id="+id+"' class='btn btn-danger' role='button'>Delete</a></p>");
          document.write("</div>");
          document.write("</div>");
          document.write("</div>");
          counter++;
          if(counter%3==0){
           document.write("</div>");
          }
        }
      } else {
        for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
          var id = myArray[i][4];
          if(counter%3==0){
            document.write("<div class='row'>");
          }
          if(street==myArray[i][0] || suburb==myArray[i][1] || pc==myArray[i][2] || type==myArray[i][3]){
            document.write("<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>");
            document.write("<div class='thumbnail'>");
            document.write("<div class='caption'>");
            document.write("<p>" + myArray[i][3] + "</p>");
            document.write("<p><a href='edit_property.php?id="+id+"' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Edit</a> <a href='#delete_property.php?id="+id+"' class='btn btn-danger' role='button'>Delete</a></p>");
            document.write("</div>");
            document.write("</div>");
            document.write("</div>");
            counter++;
          }
          if(counter%3==0){
           document.write("</div>");
          }
        }
      }
    }
    createTable();
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS? What do you mean that the "CSS will not run"?

Comment: I would consider using more modern techniques than the 1990's `document.write` - having said that, you say your `CSS wont run` - and you haven't posted any CSS

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write, use a variable and replace or add the content inside an element.

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq14qot3/

```
var myArray = [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]];
    var createTable = function() {
        var street = document.getElementById("search-street").value;
        var suburb = document.getElementById("search-suburb").value;
        var pc = document.getElementById("search-pc").value;
        var type = document.getElementById("search-type").value;
        var counter = 0;
        var outputHTML = '';
        if (street == '' && suburb == '' && pc == '' && type == '') {
            for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                var id = myArray[i][4];
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    outputHTML += ("<div class='row'>");
                }
                outputHTML += ("<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>");
                outputHTML += ("<div class='thumbnail'>");
                outputHTML += ("<div class='caption'>");
                outputHTML += ("<p>" + myArray[i][3] + "</p>");
                outputHTML += ("<p><a href='edit_property.php?id=" + id + "' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Edit</a> <a href='#delete_property.php?id=" + id + "' class='btn btn-danger' role='button'>Delete</a></p>");
                outputHTML += ("</div>");
                outputHTML += ("</div>");
                outputHTML += ("</div>");
                counter++;
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    outputHTML += ("</div>");
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                var id = myArray[i][4];
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    outputHTML += ("<div class='row'>");
                }
                if (street == myArray[i][0] || suburb == myArray[i][1] || pc == myArray[i][2] || type == myArray[i][3]) {
                    outputHTML += ("<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>");
                    outputHTML += ("<div class='thumbnail'>");
                    outputHTML += ("<div class='caption'>");
                    outputHTML += ("<p>" + myArray[i][3] + "</p>");
                    outputHTML += ("<p><a href='edit_property.php?id=" + id + "' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Edit</a> <a href='#delete_property.php?id=" + id + "' class='btn btn-danger' role='button'>Delete</a></p>");
                    outputHTML += ("</div>");
                    outputHTML += ("</div>");
                    outputHTML += ("</div>");
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                    outputHTML += ("</div>");
                }
            }
        }
        document.body.innerHTML = outputHTML;
        alert(outputHTML);
    }
    createTable();
```

Comment: blindly overwriting `document.body.innerHTML` may not produce the exact result the OP was expecting :p

Comment: But it's close enough to a "document.write" xD

Comment: If you add CSS it will always "remain", ill update the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9ov8cLkb/

Comment: @JCHernández THANKS FOR THE HELP~ You're a life saver~ :D i did it by changing it to innerHTML, i hope i can raise this question, but my reputation is not yet 15 so i can't. but this is the correct answer